# Etalon Produces Odd Interference Pattern

Tags: interference, interferometry

The other day I created an optical cavity with a first surface mirror and a beam splitter. Here’s a pic of the interference. Has anyone seen something like this. Is it common?

[image]

Comment: how about  this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabry%E2%80%93P%C3%A9rot_interferometer

Comment: @annav I saw the one you sent. Thanks. Mine still lots a lot different though.

Comment: look at ths search https://www.google.com/search?channel=trow2&sxsrf=ALeKk01WIVbtPS_azB3L6MgOiTflKtkBZw:1591689364066&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=etalon+interference+patterns+photos&client=firefox-b-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi17Yz5oPTpAhXHMJoKHbPSAuoQ7Al6BAgGECw&biw=1525&bih=730

Comment: I think the OP's question  is about the mysterious discontinuities in his (non-)circular fringes. Part of the beam is suffering an unexpected phase shift.

Comment: @mikestone yes what do you think is going on?

Comment: You need to show details of how youur interferometer is built. No scotch tape that part of the light is going though?